# Adjust the position of the JFrame next to the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to set the position of the `JFrame` A next to the `JFrame` position B.

My code is:

```
   JFrame instance = A;
   B.setLocation(instance.getLocation().x+instance.getSize().width
                                , instance.getLocation().y+0);
```

But I get a space betweens `JFrames`.

Look at picture: [IMAGE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrjEP.png)

How can I fix it? Is there some border offset?

Comment: Windows 10?  This is likely a shadowing effect introduced by the OS, which is part of the outer frame decorations, over which you have little to no control

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, windows 10. Ok, thank you.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)